ADB - "adb.exe: unknown command jdb"
I have installed JDK22, JAVA, Bluestacks and Android Studio SDK yet I think I dont have JDB installed:
adb.exe: unknown command jdb

enter image description here
ADB is working properly though:
enter image description here
JDWP also works.
What could be the problem? I dont see anyone else having this issue before on internet. How can I fix it?
Reinstalled JDK22, switched back to 21. Reinstalled Android Studio, installed another emulator.

Not every exe that exists in your system is in the PATH thus can be executed without the full path. The tools from JDK are usually also not included in PATH therefore you have to provide the full path to jdb.exe to execute it. bTW please don't post screenshots of terminal output. It is just text so just copy and paste it jnzk your question and format it as code. I would also like to know why you write a question about jdb and then mention and tag it adb. That doesn't fit together...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
